# Is there any way to automatically rewrite URL's when you deploy a spring mvc project to tomcat?

Tags: spring, url, tomcat, deployment, spring-mvc

So I'm working with Spring MVC for the first time. 
I've created an application using IntelliJ and everything works fine, but now I'm trying to deploy this application to tomcat.
I've got the war file "myapplication.war" and when I deploy it to tomcat I can successfully surf to localhost:8080/myapplication . 
On this page I've got a link to one of my controllers.

```
<a href="/register">Register</a>
```

Which redirects me to localhost:8080/register instead of localhost:8080/myapplication/register.
If I change the URL myself it works fine.

Is there any way to rewrite this URL automatically ? 
I don't want to change all the URL in my project because then it will be impossible to run it from IntelliJ.

Comment: Are you using jsp?  If so then use `<c:url>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dislike `<c:url...>` as it requires two line of JSP where other templating engines usually require just one. An alternative is:

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/register">Register</a>
```

This will effectively do the same thing as `<c:url...>`

Edit: should be a simpler task of changing all URLs in your IDE:

search: `href="/`
replace: `href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/`

Answer (score 5):

use `<c:url>` from

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

Eg:

```
<c:url var="registerVar" value="/register" />
...
<a href="${registerVar}">Registration</a>
```

Comment: (+1) this is the only correct way, Btw it will also enable the fallback to link based session ids, instead of cookies.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in **http://localhost:8080/myapplication/welcome** and your link is **href="register"** (without slash) you'll be redirected to **http://localhost:8080/myapplication/register**.

The problem is when you are in **http://localhost:8080/myapplication/foo/bar**. Then, the same link will redirect you to **http://localhost:8080/myapplication/foo/register**. What I do for dealing with this is use base tag. If you put **<base href="http:/localhost:8080/myapplication" />** in head tag it will work in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

When you rename the applications war to `ROOT.war` (upper case letters for "ROOT"!) then the application will run without any "prefix".

Answer (score 0):

Create filter that include base as attribute, for example for `/src/java/company/project/web/filter/BaseFilter.java`:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.*;

/**
 * Make sane JSP, instead of:
 *   <pre>&lt;a href="&lt;c:url value='/my/path/${id}.html'/&gt;"&gt;Title&lt;/a&gt;</pre>
 * allow to use:
 *   <pre>&lt;a href="${ctx}/my/path/${id}.html"&gt;Title&lt;/a&gt;</pre>
 */
public class BaseFilter implements Filter {
    private String min;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig fc) {
        min = fc.getServletContext().getInitParameter("min");
        if (min == null)
            min = fc.getInitParameter("min");
        if (min == null)
            min = "min";
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        request.setAttribute("base", request.getServletContext().getContextPath());
    request.setAttribute("min", min);
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() { }
}
```

and register that filter in `web.xml`:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>BaseFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>company.project.web.filter.BaseFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>BaseFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.json</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

and use clean syntax:

```
<script src="${base}/js/jquery.${min}.js"></script>
<link href="${base}/css/bootstrap.${min}.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<a href="${base}/index.html">Home</a>
```

**NOTE** I set additional attributes in that filter, for example to switch between development and minified version of CSS/JS I use `min` attribute which may be set externally to WAR file in context deployment descriptor (refer to your Java EE-container docs).

See also my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13993570/173149

Comment: ServletRequest has no method named getServletContext() (or maybe I cant see O_X )

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html vs https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html I use Tomcat 8 which is EE API v6.

Comment: Ahah ! you are right. I used your code and it worked for me . thanks.

HttpServletRequest helped me in that.